# Use AWS to store JMS messages from queue

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jms

I'm trying to store large amounts of messages coming from a service that uses JMS as a queueing system. I'm trying to understand how to use AWS to connect to this system and store the data in S3. I looked into SQS, but it doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for. I already have a queue to connect to.